# Why can't I chain a method to a constructor?

Tags: c++, qt, object

I'm trying to set a permission for a file. I thought I could save a line of code while dealing with a `QFile` object, like so.

```
QFile("somefile.txt").setPermissions(QFile::WriteOther);
```

It compiled and ran, but didn't do anything. Of course, when I did it the **right** way, it worked. (no surprise, there.)

```
QFile tempFileHandle("somefile.txt");
tempFileHandle.setPermissions(QFile::WriteOther);
```

I think this is a good opportunity to understand the C++ syntax. I'll accept that my original way doesn't work, but *why?*

Comment: [This works.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2da0f591c6bc579ec589cec3feaa8cf0) So does changing it to write that to a file opened in the ctor.

Comment: Syntax wise it looks fine as chris demonstrated so it is probably Qfile behaviour possibly...

Comment: A temporary object is basically `const`. One possibility is that there are two overloads of `setPermissions`, one for non-const QFile (used by your second example) and a second for `const` QFile (used by your first example) that apparently doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Is that really the case? According to that, [this code](http://liveworkspace.org/code/fb30e43357fb2cdaa2c3ef8f67bb6814), should print "const", but it doesn't.

Comment: @jrok: Thus the "basically". A temporary isn't actually `const`, but still won't (for one example) bind to a non-const reference, only to a const reference. Without tearing into the code for QFile, it's hard to be sure exactly what's going on.

Comment: I know that, but there are no references involved here. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The Qt library 4.8 has two `setPermissions` functions: (i) a non-const `Qfile::setPermissions` function, taking a single argument and (ii) a non-const _static_ `QFile::setPermissions` function taking two arguments, a filename and permissions. The existence of latter overload in the `QFile` class, suggests this is an attempt by the library authors(for some unknown reason) to mimic anonymous temps calls via an overloaded static function.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I beg to differ, in both cases the non-const member will be called (proof http://ideone.com/d7qBl3)

Comment: @JerryCoffin IMHO the binding of non-const references is not relevant here, although your statement is true (example code: https://ideone.com/DkpbYx).

Comment: What QT library version are you using?

Comment: I compiled and ran under 4.8.1.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know QFile and don't know exactly what your observation is but it probably boils down to whatever is done in QFile's destructor.

The first example creates temporary object. I guess its constructor creates somefile.txt. Then setPermissions sets whatever you specified on that file. Now the question is what destructor does:

- It may delete file, and you see nothing
- It may (I wouldn't expect this but who knows) set file read only
- Revert to some defaults

In the other example you create named variable which is not destroyed until it goes out of scope and you probably can even detach the object from the file on disk which will probably nullify destructor effects on that file.

Comment: This is the only rational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you say it compiled and ran but didn't do anything. Does setPermissions() even get called, have you checked? It looks to me like the compiler has optimised out this entire line because you are working purely on a temporary object.

Comment: The compiler is not allowed to do that.